# Why am I getting a runtime error of 3022?

Tags: ms-access

I am getting a runtime error of 3022 (duplicate values in index, etc.), but the data is added to the table without any problems.

In detail, I click my Save button. The data is added to the table, but I'm still receiving a runtime error on rst.update.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblReload", dbOpenDynaset)

If IsNull(Me!txtReloadOrderNumber) Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter the PO Number.")
    Exit Sub
End If

If varFormNewEdit = False Then
    With rst
        .AddNew
        !ReloadDate = Me!txtReloadDate
        !ReloadRailroad = Me!txtReloadRailroad
        !ReloadOrderNumber = Me!txtReloadOrderNumber
        !ReloadOrderWeight = Me!txtReloadOrderWeight
        !ReloadDestination = Me!txtReloadDestination
        !ReloadCityState = Me!txtReloadCityState
    End With
Else
    With rst
        .FindFirst "[ReloadOrderNumber]=" & varReload
        .Edit
        !ReloadDate = Me!txtReloadDate
        !ReloadRailroad = Me!txtReloadRailroad
        !ReloadOrderNumber = Me!txtReloadOrderNumber
        !ReloadOrderWeight = Me!txtReloadOrderWeight
        !ReloadDestination = Me!txtReloadDestination
        !ReloadCityState = Me!txtReloadCityState
    End With
End If

rst.Update
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent too much time on this. As soon as I posted the question, a light bulb went off. I had code written in two event procedures, on click and on enter.

This worked fine until I had turned off the default attribute on the Save button. So I was firing both events when I pressed enter on the Save button, which is why I would be getting a runtime error.

Thanks!